# Parsing table using nested FindElement with xpath (in JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm a bit new to selenium and xpath and am curious if I'm doing something right and how findElement will behave. I've looked and looked for an example but I can't find one.

Given this Table (simplified but relevant)

```html
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>R1C1</td>
          <td>R1C2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>R2C1</td>
          <td>R2C2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

If I use the following, will I have the info I'm expecting?

```
WebElement r1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]"));
String r1c1 = r1.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]")).getText();
String r1c2 = r1.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]")).getText();

WebElement r2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]"));
String r2c1 = r1.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]")).getText();
String r2c2 = r1.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]")).getText();
```

Alt:

```
String r2c1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]")).findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]")).getText();
```

Please keep in mind this is HIGHLY simplified in comparison to what I'm actually doing, but I'm confident the rest will work. My question revolves specifically around finding an element off of another element. And, no, there are no unique Class/ID tags I can utilize to specifically identify a given cell of the table.

Will this work as I expect it to? (I realize I could just try it, but then the answer wouldn't be available online for the next person to search for)

Comment: Prefix the xpath you are using to find element inside another element with a '.'   For example, r1.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[1]")).getText();

Comment: More details here -- https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: Boom, there it is. Thanks!

Comment: also `List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr"));` and then iterate `for(WebElement row : rows)`, rather than having code for every row

Comment: That's what I'm actually doing, but I didn't want to type all that out and wasn't relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to **`Keep It Short and Simple`** for a better **`Execution Performance`**.

If you want to `getText()` from the following four `WebElements` keep it as simple as :

```
String r1c1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tbody/tr/td")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String r1c2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tbody/tr//following::td[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

String r2c1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tbody//following::tr[2]/td")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String r2c2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tbody//following::tr[2]//following::td[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Sure sure. What I'm actually doing is looping through a collection of rows so I needed to pull the table cells based off the Row WebElement.

Comment: I am not sure if my Answer have catered to your question or not. If so please mark it accepted.

Comment: While your comment did add value, the answer I was looking for is in the comments of the original question.